# Connect Docker container to machine's localhost

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking, mailhog

I'm using Jenkins for the first time and have chosen to use its Docker image instead of installing it locally.
I used this Docker compose:

```
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home 
    restart: unless-stopped
    

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
```

I am trying to test the emailing features and for that have needed to use MailHog, which I also used as a Docker images, using the Docker compose below:

```
services:
  email:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    platform: linux/amd6
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:1025:1025" # SMTP
      - "127.0.0.1:8025:8025" # web UI
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Now I have configured Jenkins to use SMTP and the port 1025:
[image]
[image]
Except when I try to test this, I get the following error:
[image]

I think that since Jenkins is on a Docker container, it looks for its own localhost, maybe?
I tried to do an ipconfig and get the IP address of my machine to replace localhost but it didn't work.
Do you have any idea how to solve this please? and thank you!

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming-related question.  But the canonical question on how to make localhost connect to its host system when localhost is a Docker container is [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) and possibly one of the setups there will help you.

Comment: If you put both services into the same compose file they will be able to talk to eachother, the service name will resolve to the container, i.e. you can configure the SMTP server with hostname `email` on jenkins and it should work. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Yes thank you I put them both in a docker compose file and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine two service in one docker-compose file, and they(two container) can find each other just use service name.

Therefore, you can set 'email' as SMTP SERVER.

```
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home 
    restart: unless-stopped
  email:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    platform: linux/amd6
    ports:
      - "1025:1025" # SMTP
      - "8025:8025" # web UI
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  jenkins_home:
```

> I tried to do an ipconfig and get the IP address of my machine to
> replace localhost but it didn't work.

If you wanna use IP address of your machine, you should remove 127.0.0.1 of port configuration.